# Toggle replace characters/diactritics without class

Tags: javascript, string, replace, character

I am trying to replace some characters in php string text that doesn't have a a class, and could be anywhere in the page.

I tried something like this (to remove "w" letter"), but it works with `p` or `br`.. etc. but not with normal characters.  Or giving it list of characters to remove from text like `$("w|r|e").toggle();`.

The text is changing in various places, but all are in a `<div id="bodytext">`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button-hide2").click(function(){
        $("w").toggle();
    });
});
    });
</script>
```

This is the hide button:

`<button-hide2 id="mybtn">Toggle</button-hide2>`

And this is an example of **any** text that is in a div (the text changes with every page):

```
<div id="bodytext">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod 
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a potential solution if you have at least an understand of the HTML structure of where the text might live

```
// Take a snapshot of the original document body
const BodyCopy = document.body.cloneNode(true);

const button = document.querySelector('#mybtn');

// Regex of text we are searching for
const textWeAreSearchingFor = new RegExp(/l|r|m/, 'ig');
// Replace them with an empty string
const replaceWith = '';
// Hang on to the original version of the HTML
const originalText = BodyCopy.querySelector('#bodytext').innerHTML;
// Manage the state on whether or not it has been toggled
let isOriginal = true;

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const textArea = document.querySelector('#bodytext');

  if (isOriginal) {
    const allParagraphs = document.querySelectorAll('#bodytext p');

    // Map over all of the paragraphs and replace their text
    [...allParagraphs].map(p => {
      const currentParagraphText = p.innerText;
      const updatedText = currentParagraphText.replace(textWeAreSearchingFor, replaceWith);

      p.innerText = updatedText;
    });

    isOriginal = false;
  } else {
    // Replace with original content
    textArea.innerHTML = originalText;
    isOriginal = true;
  }  
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. not the text changes from one page to another..  I just need a button to click on it, and it removes some letters in any given text in `<div id="bodytext">`.

Comment: @mike - This isn't related to separate pages. Can you give me an example of the potential code on a page and what you might want to click to make this happen?

Comment: Thanks - I've updated my solution based on the example.